# LED and Photodiode Data Acquirement System

Tags: operational-amplifier, led, photodiode

So I am to develop a project this semester and wanted to be shed some light on certain topics.
The goal of the project is the following: Detect a pendulum's period using an LED and a photodiode and it has to work in daylight conditions.

The system I thought about using (still untested,) which will be later sent to an ATMega microcontroller:

1. LED/PD
2. Transimpedance op amp
3. High pass filter (for DC cutoff, hopefully filtering some sunlight?)
4. Buffer
5. Notch filter (cutting the 100Hz lab light)
6. Full wave precision rectifier (for all pulses to be positive)
7. Op amp for more gain.

I also figured I'd use some rubber tubes around LED and PD while directing them at each other, hopefully reducing background light in my signal.

Is there something you guys think won't work or could be improved with this system?

Also, I have no clue which LED to choose (IR, green or red) or if it makes any difference for that matter. Maybe a green one would be easier to detect since its light carries more energy?

And finally, we get bonus points if the system can detect what material the ball on the pendulum is made out of, but honestly I am clueless to how to do this, was hoping for a hint if it isn't too much to ask.

Comment: Your optical sensor (photo- transistor or diode) will be swamped by ambient "daylight" which has a lot in it over a wide range (essentially, the sun is close to a black body radiator.) First steps are to mechanically and optically reduce that, as much as possible, including selecting a transducer with narrow-band sensitivity (or thin-film filtering it.) Second steps include choosing a narrow band pulse frequency and making your 1st electronic stage respond only to that narrow band. At this point, the rest is much simpler because you've avoiding being swamped and excluded most other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: Do some experimentation to figure out if you really need all those complicated circuits.

> we get bonus points if the system can detect what material the ball on the pendulum is made out of, ... was hoping for a hint ... .

Hint 2: You have three LEDs to work with, with different colors. Exactly how these might be used to detect the material of the ball depends a lot on the range of materials of the balls that might be used.

> Maybe a green one would be easier to detect since its light carries more energy?

Green light has more energy **per photon**. If you use IR, you can just send more photons to get the same intensity as you're getting from the green source.

Also remember, the photodiode generally generates one photoelectron per absorbed photon. So the responsivity of the photodiode (in A/W) is generally higher at longer wavelengths, specifically because the photon energy is lower.

Comment: @DKNguyen, IR blocking filters are pretty common, used in cameras (except maybe the cheapest ones).

Comment: I'm going to just delete this comment and put it in my own answer and you can response to it there where we can discuss so it doesn't muddle your answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton Sorry to ask, but by what exact mechanism does "higher energy per photon" lead to more "shot noise in the system?" I do understand the mechanism related to shot noise (the reason why current across a PN junction, for example, as the charge motion events involved do not have long range effects as they do in a wire.) I don't understand the connection about higher energy photons as the best you have is one swept charge per photon. I could learn something, perhaps.

Comment: @jonk, if you have an average of 1 pJ of energy arriving per nanosecond, then the possible arrival of one photon more or less will be a bigger relative noise in your power measurement if the energy per photon is higher.

Comment: @jonk, this is probably (for OP) not nearly as important as the difference in responsivity of a photodiode at different waelengths that DKN points out.

Comment: Edited to remove discussion of shot noise which is probably irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should look into the difference (and availability) of photodiodes and phototransistors. They are not the same. Phototransistors are easier to work with and have more inherent gain. Photodiodes are faster, and more linear but require a transimpedance amplifier. Basically photodiodes are for high-speed or analog applications (though you can press phototransistors into service for analog applications if you want). Yours is low-speed (as far as electronics are concerned) so you probably want a phototransistor for simplicity, especially if you only plan to be treating it as a digital interruption signal and nothing more.

It's almost stupidly easy to get a phototransistor working compared to a photo-diode. The first time I did it it took me a couple of minutes. No op-amps or transimpedance amplifiers of any kind needed. I think a photodiode with a transimpedance amplifier would be a platinum-plated solution for your application, but if you have the time to use it instead you might learn a lot more. Even if you ultimately choose a photodiode, it is worthwhile to wire up a phototransistor to a single pull resistor to just compare the results. For reference, I used a phototransistor and a resistor detect a thin notch scribed into a a motor shaft spinning at either 1800 or 3600RPM (I forget) and it worked just fine.

Green photons are more energetic than IR, but don't forget that silicon (the most common material used) is most sensitive in the near-IR and also the most emissive in the near IR so that can offset it quite a bit.

You can also get near-IR photodiodes/phototransistors that are have a built-in visible blocking filter in them (they will look opaque black) so you don't have to worry about fluorescent flicker. This would eliminate the need for DC-blocking as far as light flicker is concerned (unless think fluorescent lights emit near IR, but I don't think they do), though there may be other reasons you may want DC-blocking. I've always found external optics to be difficult to get ahold of, cumbersome to work with, and expensive.

It's also easier to get infrared emitters and detectors with a very narrow beam which also helps ignore interference, not to say you can't find the same in the visible spectrum. Don't look straight into these LEDs. They can be almost laser level brightness, especially the infrared ones you cannot see. This lets you get away without needing a tube. If you do work with IR and have a tube, just remember that not everything opaque to our eyes is opaque to IR, especially plastic materials.

You could also modulate your light if there interferences in your the spectral band of sensitivity, but that takes more circuitry.

Note that the readings from either a photo-diode or phototransistor might not be as "digital" as you want so you may want a comparator in there. Otherwise you would have to use the ADC on the MCU which would slow things down (but ultimately probably won't matter since your pendelum is probably so much slower anyways).

You could use a through-beam approach like you proposed. That would be more sensitive, but if you find alignment issues to be a problem then you could go with a reflective approach where emitter and detector are side-by-side. That works and is mechanically simpler. Up to you.

As for detecting material...I don't know how specific you have to get but through-beam could detect how transparency a material might be (you might need too powerful a beam though if the material is thick or not very transparent) That would allow you to differentiate from metal and some kinds of plastics, at least. This would require processing the analog output (i.e. using an ADC and no comparator).

A reflective approach obviously could detect how reflective a material might be but which would probably also differentiate between shiny metal and dull materials (wood, plastic). Unless the metal was coated with something.

Comment: Hadn't thought about the reflective aproach ! Will surely try them both out ! Thank you so much ! It also could help with the material detection. I assume I would have to test with different materials to find the respective (aproximate) voltage levels of each in the signal I would get from this system, no ?

Comment: @DeltaXGamerPT Yeah, it will be a grind to tabulate material data. Distance will also matter too and your pendelum is probably going to be round (i.e. distance from sensor to surface varies as it moves across your field of view). You could use emitters at multiple wavelengths and and spectrally limited detectors (more difficult to find) to just try and identify by colour characteristics. Since wavelength specific detectors are more difficult to find, you could just use one broadband detector and continuously flash the emitters separately.

Answer (score 0):

Given the need to tolerate daylight, and presumably incandescent bulbs and flourescents of 60Hz and 80,000Hz arc-rates, and LEDs of various, I offer this **ADAPTIVE** photo-transistor circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPzTIh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit adjusts for varying DC photon fluxes. Also nulls out most of the very slow changes, thus 60Hz will be somewhat attenuated. The high frequency photon variations should be detected fully, thus high-frequency flourescents are not attenuated.

Answer (score 0):

> **6. Full wave precision rectifier (for all pulses to be positive)**

A simple transimpedance amplifier (AC-coupled to block DC daylight) would give output voltage having both positive-going edges and negative-going edges. Accepting these pulses into your ATmega microcontroller's analog-to-digital converter might be an option worth considering. You may have to add a DC offset so that negative pulses can be properly detected.
This allows you to *unambiguously determine* when the light beam is blocked, and when it is unblocked. Converting all pulses with a rectifier circuit can easily cause confusion, when you consider that pendulum amplitude decays to the point when the blocked period is similar to the unblocked period.
Processing detected light with analog-to-digital conversions also allows you to use software to determine pulse timing, rather than hardware. Consider which are your stronger skills: hardware or software.

---

ATmega's analog-to-digital converter limits your timing resolution because each sample requires many microseconds to be acquired...a disadvantage. Time resolution of ATmega's timer/counters are potentially better, which favours processing pulses with hardware circuits.

Comment: Thanks for this ! I will certainly look into it and rethink about the rectifier, after some experimentation

Answer (score 0):

The tried and true method for optical transmission detection of an object is to use IR emitter and IR detection with a black lens that passes only IR light.

These are inexpensive and were developed by Sharp a leader in the optical electronics market for many apps and subsequently sold to Vishay.

The most popular ones are in 5mm cases and cane easily be shielded from stray reflections using a length of heatshrink tubing or a custom black enclosure with recessed Diodes and small apertures.

The signal detection can be detected at 25% of the peak level or 75% loss or differentiated for the change in level.  Aiming accuracy depends on optical geometry and gain/Angle beamwidth of the lenses.
Given the integrity of SNR from optical alignment tubular light pipe and daylight blocking filter the choice of PD gain resistor needs to be chose but the choice of optical components is not critical for short paths say < 10cm . Narrow emitters would be a better choice to utilize the optical power into 0.5 mA/mW PD sensors.

I can look up the SF part numbers for you, but they should be easy to find.

Given a time interval pulse, it is trivial to measure the error frequency if you have a frequency reference better than your expected null tolerance whether it is 10, 1 ppm  or less.  1ppm resolution requires a 1MHz Clk  or one can use PLL multiplier to create a higher LF signal such as 10kHz then 1ppm error would be measuring a frequency up to 100 Hz, which could be done with 32kHz uC.

Since a pendulum reaches bottom dead centre twice each second It is necessary to use only 1 direction and edge of the pendulum regardless if rising or fall  edge. Your choice.